# What is the Maximum size of DLL file that can be loaded in XBox360

Tags: dll, size, xbox360

I have developed game on XBox360 platform. I embed some game resources in my source code (c#). So it makes my DLL is very large (about 16 MB). In PC, it's fine, DLL can be loaded. But it 's not work in XBox. It throw an exception like this

An unhandled exception of type 'System.MissingMethodException' occurred in Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.dll
Additional information: File or assembly name 'MyDLL, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null', or one of its dependencies, was not found.

Then I exclude some my resources to reduce my DLL size (to ~14 MB). So it can be loaded in XBox. Is ~16MB is the maximum size of DLL that can be loaded in XBox360 ? Is there any way to load the larger DLL in XBox360 ?

Comment: How are you embedding the resources, and why do they have to be embedded?

Comment: My game resource includes level file which describes all level object geometries, checkpoint and the other information. Actually it is an XML file. But I found that it takes too long time to load. So I decide to bypass reading XML process by hard code them all as c# file. And build it as .DLL